# How can I delete the first entries from a string

Tags: c, arrays, string, printf

This is my task: Write a program that reads a string w of maximum length m = 100 and two indices a; b element of [1; 100], with a smaller or equal than b from the keyboard. Then, the substring starting with w[a-1] and ending with w[b-1], shall be printed on the screen. I am not allowed to use functions or loops.
Example: input: w = "sundown", a = 2, b = 5. output: "undo"

I created this program, but I did not get the last step.

```
int main(){

    char w[100];
    int a, b;

    printf("Please insert a value for a and b, where b is greater than a: ");
    printf("\na = ");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    printf("\nb = ");
    scanf("%d", &b);

    printf("Now please insert a phrase, which is at most 100 character long:\t");
    scanf("%100s", &w);

    w[b] = '\0';

    printf("w = %s", w);
}
```

Comment: Remember a `char[100]` can **only hold 99 bytes of text** as the last byte is reserved for the terminator.

Comment: Assign a null terminator to `w[b]`, and use pointer arithmetic to print `w+a`.

Comment: `scanf("%100s", &w);` with this `char w[100];` is absolutely dangerous. Because `scanf` with the format specifer `%s` writes a terminating `\0` after the string you input, and this one will be stored outside the buffer if you do it like that and input a string comprises of 100 characters. Use `scanf("%99s", &w);` instead.

Comment: do yourself a favor and avoid using scanf to read from the keyboard, instead use fgets and convert to the desired type e.g. atoi or use sscanf if you must.

Answer (score 0):

I do not use it too often but I think

```
printf ("%.*s\n", b -a, w + a - 1);
```

To print something you need functions

Or your way

```
w[b ] = '\0';

    printf("w = %s", w+ a-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int first = 2;
int length = 5;

printf("%.*s\n", length - 1, w + first - 1);
```

Comment: How this answer ia distinct from my one?

Comment: There is no difference boss, we were just posting at the same time

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by making the size of w two bytes longer or `char w[102];` and using a null character at the beginning and end of the string. In this case, you just use a pointer (as in `char *w_begin;` and `char *w_end;`) to point to the character after the first null character and to point to the end of the string that you would want to print. Using this approach, the string starting at `w_begin` and ending just before `w_end` is printed.